# Find distance between two points in Kilometers with the help of latitude and longitude (Geometry)in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, distance

I have this code but its not give appropriate output in kilometers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distance (Lat1    IN NUMBER,
                                     Lon1    IN NUMBER,
                                     Lat2    IN NUMBER,
                                     Lon2    IN NUMBER,
                                     Radius  IN NUMBER DEFAULT 3963)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   -- Convert degrees to radians
   DegToRad  NUMBER := 57.29577951;
BEGIN
   RETURN (  NVL (Radius, 0)
           * ACOS (
                  (  SIN (NVL (Lat1, 0) / DegToRad)
                   * SIN (NVL (Lat2, 0) / DegToRad))
                + (  COS (NVL (Lat1, 0) / DegToRad)
                   * COS (NVL (Lat2, 0) / DegToRad)
                   * COS (
                        NVL (Lon2, 0) / DegToRad - NVL (Lon1, 0) / DegToRad))));
END;
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your current output and desired output? Also please do keep in mind that the result may vary compare to maps like google.

Comment: Location 1 latitude:33.6844 longitude: 73.0479 ; location 2 latitude:34.1688 ,longitude: 73.2215 The output is: 34.95466521655557688036018398657443860336, but the output should be 159 Kilometers

Comment: Why should the answer be 159km? Putting it into on-line calculators it comes out as 56km. (Also, you have put the radius of the Earth in miles instead of km and have used the equatorial radius rather than a globally-average radius.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION haversine_distance(
  lat1  IN NUMBER,
  long1 IN NUMBER,
  lat2  IN NUMBER,
  long2 IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  PI           CONSTANT NUMBER := ASIN(1) * 2;
  R            CONSTANT NUMBER := 6371; -- Approx. radius of the earth in km
  PHI1         CONSTANT NUMBER := lat1 * PI / 180;
  PHI2         CONSTANT NUMBER := lat2 * PI / 180;
  DELTA_PHI    CONSTANT NUMBER := (lat2 - lat1) * PI / 180;
  DELTA_LAMBDA CONSTANT NUMBER := (long2 - long1) * PI / 180;
  a NUMBER;
  c NUMBER;
BEGIN
  a := SIN(delta_phi/2) * SIN(delta_phi/2) + COS(phi1) * COS(phi2) *
          SIN(delta_lambda/2) * SIN(delta_lambda/2);
  c := 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1-a));
  RETURN R * c; -- in kilometres
END;
/
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT haversine_distance(
         lat1 => 33.6844, long1 => 73.0479, lat2 => 34.1688, long2 => 73.2215 
       ) AS distance
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | DISTANCE |
> | --- |
> | 56.1938360038059453699709826045549961225 |

Or, you can use `SDO_GEOM`:

```sql
SELECT sdo_geom.sdo_distance(
         sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(73.0479, 33.6844, null), null, null),
         sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(73.2215, 34.1688, null), null, null),
         0.005,
         'unit=km'
       ) AS distance
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs:

> | DISTANCE |
> | --- |
> | 56.0766116774312 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0c50a6fae2873876f06cca23911ce66e)*

Comment: The output should be 159 km

Comment: @Ahmed Why? The straight-line distance from Islamabad to Abbottabad is 56km.

Comment: You are right .The actual distance is 159 KM but incase of straight-line distance the answer is correct. Thanks to guide.